# high level design of a browser layout engine?

Tags: architecture, browser

I'm interested in how browser layout engines like gecko, webkit and trident are architected from a high level. what are the key abstractions? how are they layered? what are the inputs/outputs for the different abstractions? Is there a diagram or article that explains this particularly well?

I am sure the implementations vary, but I'm generally curious about how all the pieces fit together. I realize webkit is open source and I can just look at the code, but I wouldn't know where to start.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A few papers that will help you get a better understating of browser architecture:

- [A Reference Architecture for Web Browsers](http://grosskurth.ca/papers/browser-refarch.pdf)
- [Architecture and evolution of the modern web browser](http://grosskurth.ca/papers/browser-archevol-20060619.pdf)
- [Conceptual Architecture of Firefox](http://web.uvic.ca/~hitchner/assign1.pdf)
- [The Security Architecture of the Chromium Browser](http://seclab.stanford.edu/websec/chromium/chromium-security-architecture.pdf)

Be warned, the links are to pdf files. The last one is not exactly what you are looking for, but it's a good read. As for specific layout engines:

**Gecko**

- [Mozilla's Layout Engine](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/newlayout/doc/layout-2006-12-14/master.xhtml), presentation by [David Baron](http://dbaron.org/)
- [Gecko Overview](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko%3aOverview), in the [Mozilla Wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Main_Page)

**Webkit**

You can find some basic architectural diagrams in this [presentation on Developing hybrid Web GTK+ applications](http://www.atoker.com/blog/2008/02/26/developing-hybrid-web-gtk-applications/) by Alp Toker.

**Trident**

- [Internet Explorer Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), on MSDN

Comment: fantastic Yannis, this is just what I was looking for. thanks

Comment: And:  (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/)

Answer (score 3):

The following links may also be useful:

- [How Browsers Work: Layout](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Layout) - Gecko and WebKit
- [Gecko Overview: Layout](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko%3aOverview#Layout) - a bit more difficult to follow